# Change radio values and associate with specific id in database and html tables

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I have an ajax request generating a table that looks like this :

```
|   ID         |   Name   |   Radio    |
========================================
|  123456      |   One    |     Y,N    |
========================================
|  789000      |   Two    |     Y,N    |
========================================
|  123456      |  Three   |     Y,N    |
========================================
|  348202      |   Four   |     Y,N    |
```

I need to store the value from those radio toggles in a database and then associate them with all rows that have that ID.  For example if I clicked on the Y button in either row 1 or row 3, I would then have Y associated with both of those rows.

I am grabbing the ID from the onclick of the button and then passing that through a form value to the db table.   Any ideas how to now associate each of the radio input values with their respective ID(s)?  How will it work if the radio is changed?  How could I make that association and update just those values?

Any ideas, snippets, or links would be much appreciated to help me get a handle on how to do this.

### EDIT

To make sure my question is clear I do have the part where I grab the id and can associate it with a radio button.  I am using this (for my real code, not my 'sketch') :

```
$j('button').live("click", function(){
    var thisSku = $j(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
    $j('.skuContainer input').val( thisSku );
});
```

and I will post that value, the ID, to the db along with whatever is selected from the toggle.  In my real project there are multiple toggles that I will need to associate with their ID(s).

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the table first, build the IDs of the radio buttons in a special foramt that includes the ID. For example,
The ID of the radio button in the first row can be 123456-1 
The ID of the radio button in the second row can be 789000-1
The ID of the radio button in the third row can be 123456-2
The ID of the radio button in the fourth row can be 123456-1

At the onClick, you grab the ID and pass it to the DB, you update all rows with that ID with the new value.

Then after AJAX returns, you run another Javascript routine that spans all the table and look for the IDs matching this criteria: 123456-*, you get these radio buttons and toggle them to ON. This will take care of all rows being displayed in the current table view (I assume you might have the table split across several pages).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you might do it:

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q8kry/1/

HTLM

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123456</td><td>One</td><td>Yes<input type="radio" value="0" name="One" />No<input type="radio" value="1" name="One" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>789000</td><td>Two</td><td>Yes<input type="radio" value="0" name="Two" />No<input type="radio" value="1" name="Two" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123456</td><td>Three</td><td>Yes<input type="radio" value="0" name="Three" />No<input type="radio" value="1" name="Three" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Get Values" />
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#btnTest").click(function(){

    var myVals = [];

    $("tr").each(function(){
       var $row = $(this);
        alert($row.find("> td:eq(2) > input:checked").val());
        myVals.push({
            id: $row.find("> td:eq(0)").html(),
            val: $row.find("> td:eq(2) > input:checked").val()
        });
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(myVals)); 

});
```

Though I do think checkboxes would work better/simplify the solution.

**EDIT**

To complete the answer you could then post myVals to the server by assigning to it a hidden form field and submitting your form (full postback). OR, you could post the value via ajax to the server and avoid a full postback.

If you wanted to only post values that have changed, you'd need to remember their values when the page loads and only add them to the myVals array if they are different from their original value.

Comment: I updated my question and hope it clarifies some.  Thanks for the fiddle, the part I am most interested in is the bit you wrote after your EDIT.  That is where I need the most help and information.  How would the radio state be updated in the database table?  Would it create a new row with that same id or overwrite the existing id state?

Comment: In your example I also need to figure out how to associate that boolean across all like numbers.  So if change from 0 to 1 it updates that value for all of the like numbers that are in different rows.